# Javascript THREEJS and GC

Tags: javascript, performance, three.js, garbage-collection, cpu

I try to optimize my threejs scene, (high increasing CPU usage even if the scene is not used).
I read lot of solutions and i try to remove memory of mesh with `dispose()` (try to avoid memory leaks)

```
labelMesh[i].geometry.dispose();
labelMesh[i].material.dispose();
```

But when i inspect the Javascript Profiler, `dispose()` increase 2 times CPU of GC.

Without dispose():
[image]

With dispose():
[image]

I keep this solution or no ? What is a best option ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I keep this solution or no ? What is a best option ?

Using `.dispose()` is definitely recommended. There is actually an official guide about this topic:

https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#manual/en/introduction/How-to-dispose-of-objects.

However, there is still an issue that impedes `three.js` to free resources even when `.dispose()` is correctly called (see https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/12447). This happens because `three.js`'s internal render lists still hold references to certain objects. Calling `.dispose()` will free GPU memory but not CPU memory because of these hidden references.

A workaround for this is to call `renderer.renderLists.dispose()`.

`three.js R107`

Comment: This is good to know. I found [this PR](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/12464) and it looks like the milestone has been set to `r108`. Does that mean that after that PR is merged, calling `Mesh.dispose()`will take care of the renderLists without having to call `renderer.renderLists.dispose()` of that separately?

Comment: Yes, calling `renderer.renderLists.dispose()` would not be necessary anymore. However, the release tag changes automatically so I'm not sure the PR will be merged in the near future. There are still some concerns about a possible performance issue that the change might introduce. However, I think there should be no problem...